# Guessing game, error on shadowing guess bind

Tags: rust

I'm following the [Rust tutorial](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/guessing-game.html) but I'm stuck on this code (the last snippet in the page):

```
extern crate rand;

use std::io;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");

    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);

    println!("The secret number is {}", secret_number);

    loop {
        println!("Please input your guess");

        let mut guess = String::new();

        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut guess)
            .expect("Failed to read line");

        let guess: u32 = guess.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => continue,
        }

        println!("You guessed: {}", guess);

        match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
            Ordering::Less      => println!("Too small!"),
            Ordering::Greater   => println!("Too big!"),
            Ordering::Equal     => {
                println!("You win!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `cargo run` I have the following error:

```
src/main.rs:23:47: 23:48 error: expected one of `.`, `;`, or an operator, found `{`
src/main.rs:23         let guess: u32 = guess.trim().parse() {
                                                             ^
```

What's the right syntax?

Comment: You forgot the `match` after the `=` assignment... Just compare it with the original code again.

Comment: A diffing tool would be invaluable to point out the differences. There are [online versions](https://www.diffchecker.com/) and command-line versions.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt thanks! I fell quite stupid right now...

Comment: @rpadovani It happens to the best of us ;)
However, checking your code and doing a minimal amount of thinking before asking on StackOverflow is expected to avoid unhelpful questions like this one.
Just keep on coding and have fun learning Rust! :3

Comment: DOH!  Going through the EXACT same tutorial and missed "match" although it is highlighted on page 28.  Stack Overflow just saved me 20 minutes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a syntax error and the compiler message is directing your attention to the wrong place on the line to fix the problem.

The `parse` method evaluates to a value. This expression should not be followed by a block, causing the syntax error reported by the compiler.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.parse

The example you linked to has the keyword `match` between the assignment and call to `parse`. The `match` keyword takes an expression and branches based on the value of the expression. The block contains the branching patterns and expressions. In this case it is also destructuring the `Result` into either an `u32` or `u32::Err`.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/match.html

Below is an example that separates the parse and match for clarity.

```
// Store result of parsing in a variable
let parse_result = guess.trim().parse();
// Destructure the result
let guess: u32 = match parse_result {
    // If parse succeeded evaluate to the number
    Ok(num) => num,
    // If parse failed repeat the loop
    Err(_) => continue,
};
```

Comment: Nice explanation. However, this is a parsing error and the parser doesn't care about the return type of `parse`. Indeed the `guess.trim().parse()` expression mustn't be followed by a code block, but again, the type doesn't matter. Maybe you could remove that part from your answer...

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add the `match` keyword before calling `guess.trim().parse()`
That line should look like  this:
`let guess : u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {...`

source: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html